# Loading 64-bit dll files in python-3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dll

I have tried loading 64-bit DLL files using `cdll`, but I am not able to do so. I can load a 32-bit DLL file though. When i load the 64-bit DLL i get `OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

I did the following to load a DLL file

```
import ctypes
libdll = cdll.LoadLibrary('edk.dll')
```

any idea on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those symptoms indicate that you are using a 32-bit version of the Python interpreter. You need to use the 64-bit version of the interpreter.